# Batch FOR loop delims not behaving

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delimiter

I am trying to return the install location of a program using REG QUERY inside a FOR loop. My command is as follows:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=REG_SZ" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamSpeak 3 Client" /V "" 2^>NUL') DO SET TSLOC=%%a
```

Now, REG QUERY on its own returns:

```
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client
```

But using the delimiter REG_SZ returns:

```
C:\Users\Jake\Desktop>FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=REG_SZ" %a IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamSpeak 3 Client" /V "" 2>NUL') DO SET TSLOC=%a
C:\Users\Jake\Desktop>SET TSLOC=Y
C:\Users\Jake\Desktop>SET TSLOC=    C:\Program Files (x86)\Team
```

So obviously I only get up to \Team at the end. I have no idea where it gets the "Y" from or why the delim is causing it to split at \Team. If I change my token # to 3 it returns:

```
peak 3 Client
```

So somehow it must be interpreting " s" as my delimiter, right?

My question is why (or if not, what is it doing?) and how can I get it to give me the whole thing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If REG QUERY returns the string below (spaces included):

```
    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client
```

... then you want *the token after the second one* separated by spaces (that is the default tokens separator), that is:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2*" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamSpeak 3 Client" /V "" 2^>NUL') DO SET TSLOC=%%b
```

Comment: Excellent! In my tired state I didn't even think about using the wildcard. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`DELIMS` is a set of characters, not a single string. Therefore any character out of `R`,`E`,`G`,`_`,`S`, or `Z` will act as a delimiter.

Comment: Goodness. I did not realise - is there any way to get it to act as a single string? Otherwise I shall have to make it 'Z' or '_' and hope they don't have one in their install path.

Either way, you are both a scholar and a gentleman; I thank you profusely.

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to do it just using batch and standard windows programs.. Can you install/use some other scripting language? Or even http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ would make it much easier..

Comment: Unfortunately not; I'll be pushing it out from my server to about 90 end users, so it needs to be a click-and-done thing (hence batch in the first place). I think I'll just use Z and list it as a caveat. Nobody has a 'Z' in their default program directories, right?

Comment: Seems unlikely. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Files doesn't show any localised versions with a 'z' in them.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
SET "tsloc=    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client"
SET "tsloc=%tsloc:*REG_SZ    =%"
ECHO +%tsloc%+
```

Since REG QUERY on its own returns:

```
(Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client
```

the above `SET` command will remove the unwanted data. Result shown between `+` to demonstrate absence of spaces.

Formula: set var=%somevar:*string1=string2%

will assign to `var` the value of `somevar` with all characters up to `string1` replaced by `string2`. The enclosing quotes in a `set` command ensure that any stray trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned.

Comment: This is a good answer, thanks. I went for the one by Aacini, however, as I need (or else see no other way) to use a for-loop to set the REG QUERY output as a variable. If I was going to do it this way, a good delim would ensure one always gets the entire string - so a character not allowed in Windows folders would be best (e.g. `?` and `:` amongst others).

Comment: The default delimiter set is space and tab. Any characters occurring between the `=` and `"` in a `delims` phrase are assigned as delimiters, overriding the default. To get the entire line, turn off delimiters using `delims="`